# What's a good adjective for "possessing integrity"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Fill in the blank: "The most ____ person I've ever met."

A reformulation of the sentence might be "The person with the most integrity I've ever met" (which in itself has problems as a sentence,) but I want the adjective form.

Wikipedia suggests "integrous" which I'm not sure is in common use.

Comment: There are bunches of synonyms of integrity online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in the following usage note by [M-W:](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/is-there-an-adjective-form-of-integrity)

> ***There is no adjective form of integrity***. You could use another adjective with a similar meaning, such as honorable, instead.
>
> Alternatively, you could use the noun integrity in a sentence like this,
>
> - “She is a woman of integrity.”
>
> ***"A man/woman of integrity" is a common expression***, and others will definitely understand it.

An adjective you may use is  ***[upstanding:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/upstanding)***

> marked by integrity - *an upstanding businessman*

As for ***[integrous](http://www.yourdictionary.com/integrous)***, its usage is very uncommon as shown in [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=integrous&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cintegrous%3B%2Cc0):

> (rare) Having or characterized by integrity

Usage notes:

> ***In common usage, integrity is much more common than its adjectival form, integrous.***  Most speakers and writers opt for an etymologically unrelated synonym — such as honest, decent, or virtuous — when trying to express an adjectival equivalent of integrity.

(yourdictionary.com)

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion for an adjective is

> The most **principled** person I've ever met.

Examples may be found at [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/principled).

Answer (score 1):

Thesaurus:

- The most honest/ sincere/ forthright person I've ever met

Alternatives:

- Both honest and trustworthy
- The most honorable person I have ever met
- Most likely to uphold the moral code
- Least corruptible person
- Most ethical person I have ever met

Comment: **forthright** doesn't quite have it.