# Adjective corresponding to "integrity" in a technology field

Tags: meaning, adjectives

I've already found these two questions:

[What's a good adjective for "possessing integrity"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/429653/50941)

[What is the adjectival form for the word "integrity?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/5120/50941)

but the corresponding answers don't really fit my bill, because they focus exclusively on a figurative meaning of "having (moral) integrity". I need an adjective that can be used in a strictly technological context. Example:

*As a consequence of the event the crystal structure has lost its integrity.*

Somebody in the aforementioned threads suggested ***integrous***, albeit it seems to be a rare word. Can that adjective be used in the following way:

*As a consequence of the event the crystal structure is no longer integrous.*

without sounding too bizarre or out-of-date. Or is there a better alternative, considering the context is a technical document or a technical speech?

Comment: There is no common adjectival form of integrity, as those related questions demonstrate. In some cases there is a different adjective in technical and non-technical senses but none seems to exist here. Use "with/has/possessing/lost/without integrity".

Comment: Right. There doesn't seem to be a custom of using it as an adjective. Instead we use _integrity_ as a measurable quantity that one can possess, and talk about _gaining, retaining, losing,_ and _having_ integrity. Sloppy but sufficient.

Comment: *Sound* might fit.

Comment: "Complete" or "coherent" maybe?

Comment: @banuyayi No, sorry. To have integrity, in that technical context, means that the structure is unbroken. Coherent would be wrong. Complete has not the same meaning: something could have lost its structural integrity without losing some pieces. For examples, some materials when exposed to intense heat may become brittle, hence losing structural integrity, but they won't miss any parts.

Comment: Related: https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/is-there-an-adjective-form-of-integrity#:~:text=A%20reader-,Answer,%2C%20such%20as%20honorable%2C%20instead.

Answer (score 1):

**intact**

> As a consequence of the event the crystal structure is no longer
> *intact.*

[Intact](https://search.yahoo.com/search?fr=mcafee&type=E211US1441G0&p=intact%20meaning) *adjective* [OL&G]

> not damaged or impaired in any way; complete:
> "the church was almost in ruins but its tower remained intact"

That is, if by [integrity](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/integrity) [M-W] you mean *an unimpaired condition* or *state of being complete or undivided,* generally.

Example in a Technology Context

> Formatting a hard drive also erases Windows. But there are methods you
> can use to wipe a hard drive and keep Windows intact!
>
> –How to Wipe Your Hard Drive While Leaving the OS Intact
> [[makeuseof.com]](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-wipe-your-hard-disk-drive-leaving-the-os-intact/)

More here on *intact* from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intact.) and [The Word Counter](https://thewordcounter.com/meaning-of-intact/).

Answer (score 0):

Trivially, '**perfect crystal structure**' has been used [[Physics Forum; perfect crystal – is there such a thing? Apr 8, 2007](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/perfect-crystal-is-there-such-thing.164697/)]

but 'imperfect crystals' and 'the defect crystalline state' are more commonly found (eg [The Chemistry of Imperfect Crystals: Physics Today; 1964](https://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.3051186)).

As @Stuart says and implies, and as I'm sorry to say I believe to be true, no common adjective, and no form of adjective of *integrity*  that would not sound unnatural to outlandish here, exists.

Answer (score 0):

**Integral** [[M-W]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/integral): Lacking nothing essential; entire.